# Typescript & Socket io concurrency

Tags: javascript, typescript, concurrency, socket.io

I'm creating a game server and I'm stuck in an issue that I believe I need guidance in.

I'm now working on the player queue and how to handle queueing and joining.

I have a map of arrays each array hold the queue for the player of a certain tier.

Right now I let users emit a request to "joinClassic" channel and then from there I determine their tier, find first player in the tier queue and match them with each other, or add the new user to the queue.

code:

```js
// Map of queues

 private classicQueue: Map<Number, ClassicQueueObject[]> = new Map()

  constructor(private readonly serverService: ServerService) {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
      this.classicQueue.set(i, []);
    }
  }


// Join classic & findClassicOpponent

@SubscribeMessage('joinClassic')
  joinClassic(@ConnectedSocket() client:Socket, @MessageBody() payload: any): Observable<WsResponse<any>> | any{
    const clientObject = this.decryptPayload(client.id, payload);
    if (clientObject !== null){
      if (this.classicQueue.get(clientObject.tier).length === 0){
        this.classicQueue.get(clientObject.tier).push(clientObject);
        return {
          'success': true,
          'state': 'waiting'
        }
      }else{
        return this.findClassicOpponent(clientObject);
      }
    }else{
      return {
        'success': false,
        'state': "failed"
      }
    }
  }
  
  
  // == == == == === =

  findClassicOpponent(client:ClassicQueueObject){
    
    let choice: ClassicQueueObject;
    let count:number = 0
    do{
      choice = this.classicQueue.get(client.tier).shift()
      if (choice === undefined){
        this.classicQueue.get(client.tier).push(client)
        return {
          'success': true,
          'state': 'waiting'
        };

      }else{
        const ids = Array.from(this.server.sockets.adapter.rooms.keys());
        if (ids.includes(choice.clientId)){
          // client still online
          const newRoomId = genRoomId('classic', client.tier);
          this.server.in(client.clientId).in(choice.clientId).socketsJoin(newRoomId);
          this.server.to(newRoomId).emit("gameListener", {
            type: 'gameInit',
            users: [client.clientId, choice.clientId],
            roomId: newRoomId,
          });
          return {
            'success': true,
            'state': 'starting'
          };
        }else{
          if (count < 3){
            count++;
          }else{
            return {
              'success': false,
              'state': 'consuming'
            };
          }
        }
      }
    }while(choice !== undefined);
  }
```

I know that Typescript/Javascript are single threaded, but I need to handle the function joinClassic from when I get multiple user concurrent requests. The issue I'm afraid of is taking out same user from a queue for two different users' functions.

example:

> tier 1 queue = [user1, user2]
>
> user3 requesting at 00:05
>
> user4 requesting at 00:05
>
> user3 matches user1
>
> user4 matches user1

what is the probability of this scenario to happen, on a bigger scale, and how can I avoid an issue like this.